# Implementing Custom CacheDependency to invalidate ASP.Net cache item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching

I want to implement my own customCacheDependency class by deriving base CacheDependency, as provided SqlCacheDependency is not suitable for my case. (thousands of cache items, and there will so many subscriptions in SQL as well as issues with registration in ASP.Net)

I want to use this in ASP.Net VirtualPathProvider's our custom implementation, so I can pass this CustomCacheDependecy to notify the asp.net that file content in the DB has changed.

Can some one point me to any custom implementation of CacheDependency (preferably using MessageQueue)?

Thanks & Regards,
Ajay

Comment: The code example in this question answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139789/asp-net-custom-cache-dependency-refresh-all-in-at-one-moment

Answer (score 0):

The following article gives a good overview of implementing a custom CacheDependency object, even defining one that uses a timer to check for data changes which may be handy for your queue based solution presuming you will be peaking a queue periodically. If you are using a pub/sub model then your subscription logic will simply call the NotifyDependencyChanged method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163955.aspx

Best of luck!