# asp.net custom cache dependency, refresh all in at one moment

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I've got a custom cache dependency

```
class MyCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    private const int PoolInterval = 5000;
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly string _readedContent;

    public MyCacheDependency()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(CheckDependencyCallback, this, PoolInterval, PoolInterval);
        _readedContent = ReadContentFromFile();
    }

    private void CheckDependencyCallback(object sender)
    {
        lock (_timer)
        {
            if (_readedContent != ReadContentFromFile())
            {
                NotifyDependencyChanged(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string ReadContentFromFile()
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt");
    }

    protected override void DependencyDispose()
    {
        if (_timer != null) _timer.Dispose();

        base.DependencyDispose();
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but Im wondering how to make a refresh of all the object in one time. Here I put into cache 2 objects

> Cache.Insert("c1", "var1", new MyCacheDependency());
>
> Cache.Insert("c2", "vae2", new MyCacheDependency());

Its fine, but when c1 will detect change how to force c2 to don't wait 5 seconds to check but I want to call itself DependencyDispose when c1 do it.

In other words, if c1 detects change, c2 also should call DependencyDispose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could add a static event which would be fired in your CheckDependencyCallback()-method. In your constructor for the MyCacheDependency you would then attach an eventhandler. When the event is fired you could call NotifyDependencyChanged or DependencyDispose from there. In this way all MyCacheDependency-objects would react to a change.

```
class MyCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    private const int PoolInterval = 5000;
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly string _readedContent;

    public static event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public MyCacheDependency()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(CheckDependencyCallback, this, PoolInterval, PoolInterval);
        _readedContent = ReadContentFromFile();
        MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyEventHandler);
    }

   protected void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    NotifyDependencyChanged(sender, e);
   }

    private void CheckDependencyCallback(object sender)
    {
        lock (_timer)
        {
            if (_readedContent != ReadContentFromFile())
            {
                if(MyEvent!=null)
                    MyEvent(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string ReadContentFromFile()
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt");
    }

    protected override void DependencyDispose()
    {
        if (_timer != null) _timer.Dispose();

        base.DependencyDispose();
    }
}
```